# Remove item from redux array by index

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I have an array stored in my react redux store. the items consist of a `title` and that's all (no `id` field as such).

When I fire an action I try to update my store via the reducer with

```
case REMOVE_NOTIFICATION: 
    return {
        ...state,
        notifications: state.notifications.filter(id => action.id !== id)
    }
```

The `action.id` is correct but calling this doesn't seem to do anything. I expected it would return a new array of items where action.id does not match the id of the item being passed in. Am I correct to assume that `id` is in fact the array item's index?

Comment: *Am I correct to assume that id is in fact the array item's index*? nope, id will not be the item index, if you want to use the index then write it like this: `state.notifications.filter((id, index) => action.id !== index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No In filter function  first parameter is always value and second parameter is index/key

try this :)

```
case REMOVE_NOTIFICATION: 
    return {
        ...state,
        notifications: state.notifications.filter((obj,index) => {return action.id !== index})
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct to assume that id is in fact the array item's index?

No. Accordingly to [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), your **id** parameter will be the array items (content), not their index.

You may access the item's index on a second parameter on the filter function:

```
case REMOVE_NOTIFICATION: 
return {
    ...state,
    notifications: state.notifications.filter((item, index) => action.id !== index)
}
```